# Building custom POSobjects inside of loop

Tags: windows, powershell, object

Pretty new to this so please forgive me,
My mission is to create a custom object lets call it `$custOBJ`.

`$custOBJ.name` should be a string,
`$custOBJ.numbers` should be an array of numbers:

```
$custOBJ = New-Object PSObject
$custOBJ | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Name" -Value "muzi"
$numbers = @(1,11,22)
$custOBJ | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Numbers" -Value $numbers
```

So far so good, now i need to create 100 of these objects (of cours each one with different values) and then i need to create on array to hold all of the objects together, so at the end i should have
`$custOBJ1`,`$custOBJ2` ... and so on and an array
`$array = @($custOBJ1, custOBJ2 ...)`

I'm trying to do this with a for loop like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    $custOBJ[$i] = New-Object PSObject
    $custOBJ[$i] | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "test$i" -Value "testik$i"
    $numbers = @('1$i')
    $custOBJ[$i] | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Numbers" -Value $numbers
}
```

I'm getting an error, obviously this is not the correct way, Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do:
`$custOBJ[$i] =`  tries store something in the element number `$i` of the object (array) `$custOBJ`. However we don't have a numerable object named `$custOBJ` yet and with `[Number]` you can only reach positions of that object that already exist (the array needs 10 elements to be able to change element no 10).

Instead you can create the array by collectiong everything that your for(each) returns:

```
$array = for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++){    # collect the output of the for in $array
    $custOBJ = New-Object PSObject
    $custOBJ | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "test$i" -Value "testik$i"
    $numbers = @('1$i')
    $custOBJ | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Numbers" -Value $numbers
    $custOBJ  # return this instance of $custOBJ     
}
```

Or in short what [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63176037/10223991) wrote.

Answer (score 2):

A more common form would be:

```
$custOBJ = foreach ($i in 0..9){
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Test = "testik$i"
    Numbers = 0..$i
  }
}
$custOBJ


Test    Numbers
----    -------
testik0 {0}
testik1 {0, 1}
testik2 {0, 1, 2}
testik3 {0, 1, 2, 3}
testik4 {0, 1, 2, 3…}
testik5 {0, 1, 2, 3…}
testik6 {0, 1, 2, 3…}
testik7 {0, 1, 2, 3…}
testik8 {0, 1, 2, 3…}
testik9 {0, 1, 2, 3…}
```